# Android StringBuilder OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

I have a big problem with parsing some json data which I get as response from a web server. The thing that I'm doing is I get the response via POST and than convert the response as string and parse it. But in some devices I get `OutOfMemoryError` , which I'm trying to fix. Here is how I'm converting the response to string :

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream into = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    for (int n; 0 < (n = is.read(buf));) {
        into.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
    into.close();
    return new String(into.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
}
```

and here is how I'm using this piece of code :

```
InputStream response = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

        try {
            String responsee = convertStreamToString(response);
            jsonParser(responsee);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            cancelDialog("Error occurred! Please try again later.");
        }
```

Any suggestions how can I fix that problem so don't happen in all devices?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help or advices.

Comment: Have you tried it with, String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());?

Comment: I'm using `HttpURLConnection` class to make the POST statement.

Comment: Just for test purpose use HttpGet and the EntityUtils.toString() suggested by me.  If it works then nice, Else you have to Write inputstream data in file and then within file you have to read it line by line..

Answer (score 0):

The mobile has limited internal memory.

I have also face same issue. The solution that we found is that download only the necessary information. So you please confirm your requirement how much data you want to inside the mobile. If you filter the unnecessary data then the problem  will get resolved.

Before testing the program on extreme condition first check whether simple download happening if it is happening then check the limit of your data means up to how extent it will not give out of memory error. and accordingly that rework your requirement.

Comment: Actually the first time I need to download the whole json string. The next time I'm sorting it depending on the user's requirements..but the problem is in the first time. I was thinking of reading the response in chunks, but in this way it's throwing me json error.

Comment: It is giving the JSON error because the data your passing from the server is not in the JSON format. you can take the refence of the below link:http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/ . print the string that your getting from the server before reading by the json. it has to be in this particular format only: check this link - http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the string which I receive is json. The thing is that if I read the response in chunks it will cut it..and while parsing in some point it will throw an exception that json is not correct.

Comment: Why your splitting the string in the chunks from where you have taken the reference. Any reference link that you can share.the reference link that I given if you follow you definitely get the solution.